# How Can I Change a Button to a Clickable Text Doing The Same Thing That the Button Was Doing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanna change a button to a clickable text that does the same thing that the button was doing!

I tried, Google, StackOverFlow and Youtube.

this is the button,

```
  <button onclick=" mainApp.logOut()">logOut</button>
```

I´m expecting that someone can tell me a way that i can turn this code into a clickable text!

Comment: you should apply style to the button so it look like text and behave like button

Comment: clickable in the sense?? you want this text to show on input field? Can you explain lil more

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use onclick event with anchor tag

```
<a href="#" onclick='logout()'>logout</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function logout()
{
   //your code
}

</script>
```

Comment: This is not the recommended way. See the other answer

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the required `text` to which you want to apply click event in tag i:e `p` tag or `span` tag and add `click` listener to it.

```js
document.querySelector('span[role="button"]')
    .addEventListener('click', function()  {
        // call to logout function
        console.log('Listening');
    });
```

```css
.button { cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline }
```

```html
<span class="button" role="button">logout</span>
```

Comment: Maybe add a role="button"

Comment: @mplungjan - Yes. Adding role as `button` depicts its functionality and code readability.

Comment: <span onclick="whateverthefunction();" role="button" tabindex="0">Logout</span> --> clickable text, but behaves and looks like a button to screen readers (you can leave tabindex out if you don't want it to be focusable, but might confuse blind people. Because they expect a button to be focusable.

Comment: @TimB - Attaching event handlers in the `html` code is not a good practice and become difficult to manage code too.

Comment: But the markup is otherwise an improvement- for visitors who CAN see, I'd add a cursor:pointer